# HTML elements and html utilities for codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How can I get an element within an html in codename one?
Like getting the element by Id and extract information like get the innerHtml or maybe get the style or href.. etc
Are there any utilities for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XMLParser class to parse XML and traverse the tree/find elements by their ID. If you need more elaborate functionality and are willing to limit yourself to smartphones only you can use the BrowserComponent which allows you to load the HTML file and introspect it with JavaScript.